# KnockoutJS - Comparing observableArray with another observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a json data formatted like this

```
{
"ITEMS": [
    {
        "option": "one",
        "values": ["A","B","C","D"]
    },
    {
        "option": "two",
        "values": ["E","F","G"]]
    }
]
}
```

and script code like this

```
function Item(data) {
    this.option = ko.observable(data.option);
    this.values = ko.observableArray(data.values);
}

var ProductIndexVM = (function() {
  function ProductIndexVM() {

    items = ko.observable();
    filtered_items = ko.observableArray([]);

    selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {

       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(items(), function(item) { 
        // return something using compare
     });
    });


    // after ajax success
    var mappedItems = $.map(result.ITEMS, function(item) { 
      return new Item(item) 
    });
    items(mappedItems);

  }

  return ProductIndexVM;

})();
```

After successful ajax request data has been mapped into items observable. 
The problem is I need to compare **filtered_items** observableArray with item functions' **values** observableArray so that if items inside **filtered_items** match with any one of the item functions' **values** it will return that or not. 
 Simplifying whole thing I want to sort out items with only those contains in **filtered_items**. 

As an example if **filtered_items** have content same as below

```
["A", "C", "E"]
```

the output will be

```
{
"ITEMS": [
    {
        "option": "one",
        "values": ["A","C"]
    },
    {
        "option": "two",
        "values": ["E"]]
    }
]
}
```

How can I compare that inside **selectedItems**?

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing much to do with knockout, its a simple algorithmic question. Given an array of object and an array of "selected values" how can I filter the former using the latter:

```js
var input = {
  "ITEMS": [
      {
          "option": "one",
          "values": ["A","B","C","D"]
      },
      {
          "option": "two",
          "values": ["E","F","G"]
      }
  ]
}

var filters = ["A","C","E"];

var result = input.ITEMS.map(item => {
   return {
      "option": item.option,
      "values": item.values.filter(value => filters.indexOf(value)>-1)
   }
});

console.log(result);
```

Now applied to your knockout, just read your observable arrays as you normally would but use the same algorithm as demonstrated above.

Comment: I need to return items observable with filtered contents.. not direct manipulation of json data... I am doing other operations using those values...

Comment: @Nabil right, and thats what my last sentence said. Essentially where you have `// return something using compare` is just this algorithm.